# If string not in URL do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a page load I am checking if there is a string in the URL address bar and if so it should change a menu item text with that string in the URL. but if there is no string then it should write a different text.

```
var hash = document.location.hash;

// create an object to act like a dictionary to store each value indexed by its key
var partDic = {};

// remove the leading "#" and split into parts
var parts = hash.substring(1).split('&');

// If you just want the first value, whatever it is, use this.
// But be aware it's a URL so can be set to anything in any order, so this makes little sense
// var string = parts[0].split('=')[1];

// build the dictionary from each part
$.each(parts, function(i, v) {
  // do the "=" split now
  var arr = v.split("=");

  // decode to turn "%5B" back into "[" etc
  var key = decodeURIComponent(arr[0]);
  var value = decodeURIComponent(arr[1]);

  // store in our "dictionary" object
  partDic[key] = value;
});

var timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
if ("comboFilters[Agencies]" in partDic) {
    var ag = partDic["comboFilters[Agencies]"].substring(1);
    $('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html(ag).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
} else {
$('.Agency .dropdown-toggle').html("All agencies").append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
}

if ("comboFilters[Clients]" in partDic) {
    var cl = partDic["comboFilters[Clients]"].substring(1);
    $('.Client .dropdown-toggle').html(cl).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
} else {
$('.Client .dropdown-toggle').html("All clients").append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
}

if ("comboFilters[Years]" in partDic) {
    var yr = partDic["comboFilters[Years]"].substring(1).slice(1);
    $('.Year .dropdown-toggle').html(yr).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
} else {
$('.Year .dropdown-toggle').html("All years").append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
}
clearInterval(timeoutId);
}, 1000);
```

What is happening is that if there is no string, the menu item is not picking up the `else` text as it should.

The URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/#comboFilters%5BAgencies%5D=&comboFilters%5BYears%5D=.y2012
```

With that URL the menu item for Agency should pick up `All agencies` as it is empty but it is not doing it. It is printing nothing at all

Comment: Can you show what your URL looks like

Comment: sure, question updated with the URL

Comment: Instead of all that parsing, you probably can use something like `if(~parts.search('comboFilters%5BYears%5D=&')){[code if empty...]}else{[code if not empty...]}`

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into JSFiddle, adding alerts to the else clauses and they trigger just fine.

Comment: @rob.m you should be checking that there is a value with the key before adding it to your `partDic`, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as comboFilters[Agencies] is in the url parameters your code is going to create a key named comboFilters[Agencies] in `partDic` wither or not it has a value.

You need to check the value

```
//if it exists and has a non empty value
if(partDic['comboFilters[Agencies]'] && partDic['comboFilters[Agencies]'] != ""){

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Agency value is empty, but is still being added to your `partDic` list

This will check there is a value

```
$.each(parts, function(i, v) {
  // do the "=" split now
  var arr = v.split("=");

  // decode to turn "%5B" back into "[" etc
  var key = decodeURIComponent(arr[0]);
  var value = decodeURIComponent(arr[1]);

  if( value ) {
  // store in our "dictionary" object
  partDic[key] = value;
  }


});
```

Comment: it says  Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement

Comment: it should be `return`, not `continue`, its not a loop statement (eg for/while)